# Multiple starting value/convergence warnings when running glm.nb in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm running a negative binomial GLM in R. Running the model with the pooled dataset works just fine, but I'm encountering several warning messages when I attempt to run the same model for some of the smaller un-pooled (separated by animal) datasets. The model contains 12 standardized continuous variables (6 variables, each in linear and quadratic form) . The offset term 'tot' is a numeric vector. Here's a sample of the model; the real one includes all 12 predictors:

```
nb.2 = glm.nb(Count ~ offset(log(tot)) + variable1, data=anim.2)
```

I have run this for several animals and am receiving some or all of the following warnings:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 

glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Numerous searches haven't yielded any clear answers on these warnings. Please advise if more information is needed to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes warnings like these indicate that there is not enough variation in the response for certain combinations of covariates (e.g., only zeros for certain subgroups). But I have also seen situations where the algorithm converges if better starting values are provided. So these might be two aspects to check first.